# I have problem using PIP to install codimension in the pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I have a problem with downloading codimension package in the Pycharm. (I am using MacOS Mojave and Pycharm 2018.3.3.)

I tried the ways it is told on the Codimension official website, however, it did not work out either. I found it is provided as a package in the Pycharm as well. When I​ type "pip install codimension, it got stuck and showed two errors.

```
(venv) dhcp-40-136:untitled5 mengqi$ pip install codimension
Collecting codimension
Requirement already satisfied: cdmgcplugin in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: vulture==0.29 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (0.29)
Requirement already satisfied: python-magic==0.4.13 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (0.4.13)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5~=5.7 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (5.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: yapsy==1.11.223 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (1.11.223)
Requirement already satisfied: cdmpyparser in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.12.1 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (0.13.2)
Collecting cdmcfparser (from codimension)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/6f/5598a7f833aebf11167f938f0a04608f3bcc39cc4d155045f0a8e0781072/cdmcfparser-2.1.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes==1.6.0 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: qutepart in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (3.2.0)
Collecting gprof2dot (from codimension)
Requirement already satisfied: radon==2.2.0 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from codimension) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.11 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from PyQt5~=5.7->codimension) (4.19.13)
Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.3.0 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from jedi>=0.12.1->codimension) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama<0.4,>=0.3 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from radon==2.2.0->codimension) (0.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: flake8-polyfill in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from radon==2.2.0->codimension) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mando<0.7,>=0.6 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from radon==2.2.0->codimension) (0.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: flake8 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flake8-polyfill->radon==2.2.0->codimension) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mando<0.7,>=0.6->radon==2.2.0->codimension) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle<2.5.0,>=2.4.0 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flake8->flake8-polyfill->radon==2.2.0->codimension) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flake8->flake8-polyfill->radon==2.2.0->codimension) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=30 in /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg (from flake8->flake8-polyfill->radon==2.2.0->codimension) (39.1.0)
Installing collected packages: cdmcfparser, gprof2dot, codimension
  Running setup.py install for cdmcfparser ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/3n/hl1stsxj5q176s5wmkzfqp9m0000gn/T/pip-install-d7e7isw_/cdmcfparser/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/3n/hl1stsxj5q176s5wmkzfqp9m0000gn/T/pip-record-ps6pdn95/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/include/site/python3.7/cdmcfparser:
    pypandoc package is not installed: the markdown README.md convertion to rst failed
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file cdmcfparser.py (for module cdmcfparser) not found
    file cdmcfparser.py (for module cdmcfparser) not found
    running build_ext
    building 'cdmcfparser' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/thirdparty
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/thirdparty/pycxx
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/thirdparty/pycxx/Src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Ithirdparty/pycxx -Ithirdparty/pycxx/Src -Isrc -I/Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/cflowmodule.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/cflowmodule.o -Wno-unused -fomit-frame-pointer -DCDM_CF_PARSER_VERSION="2.1.4" -ffast-math -O2 -DPYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Ithirdparty/pycxx -Ithirdparty/pycxx/Src -Isrc -I/Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/cflowfragments.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/cflowfragments.o -Wno-unused -fomit-frame-pointer -DCDM_CF_PARSER_VERSION="2.1.4" -ffast-math -O2 -DPYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Ithirdparty/pycxx -Ithirdparty/pycxx/Src -Isrc -I/Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/cflowutils.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/cflowutils.o -Wno-unused -fomit-frame-pointer -DCDM_CF_PARSER_VERSION="2.1.4" -ffast-math -O2 -DPYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Ithirdparty/pycxx -Ithirdparty/pycxx/Src -Isrc -I/Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/cflowparser.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/cflowparser.o -Wno-unused -fomit-frame-pointer -DCDM_CF_PARSER_VERSION="2.1.4" -ffast-math -O2 -DPYCXX_PYTHON_2TO3
    In file included from src/cflowparser.cpp:33:
    In file included from src/cflowparser.hpp:24:
    In file included from thirdparty/pycxx/CXX/Objects.hxx:42:
    In file included from thirdparty/pycxx/CXX/Python3/Objects.hxx:45:
    In file included from thirdparty/pycxx/CXX/Python3/Exception.hxx:48:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:40:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:163:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:142:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/bitset:744:10: **error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        bool test(size_t __pos) const;
        ~~~~ ^**
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/graminit.h:52:14: note: expanded from macro 'test'
    #define test 305
                 ^
    In file included from src/cflowparser.cpp:33:
    In file included from src/cflowparser.hpp:24:
    In file included from thirdparty/pycxx/CXX/Objects.hxx:42:
    In file included from thirdparty/pycxx/CXX/Python3/Objects.hxx:45:
    In file included from thirdparty/pycxx/CXX/Python3/Exception.hxx:48:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:40:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:163:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:142:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/bitset:1015:16: error: expected unqualified-id
    bitset<_Size>::test(size_t __pos) const
                   ^
    **2 errors generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/3n/hl1stsxj5q176s5wmkzfqp9m0000gn/T/pip-install-d7e7isw_/cdmcfparser/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/3n/hl1stsxj5q176s5wmkzfqp9m0000gn/T/pip-record-ps6pdn95/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mengqi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/include/site/python3.7/cdmcfparser" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3n/hl1stsxj5q176s5wmkzfqp9m0000gn/T/pip-install-d7e7isw_/cdmcfparser/
```

Could you please help me out here? I wanted actually to visualize my code into a flowchart.

Comment: Looks like the native compilation step necessary for cdmcfparser is broken somehow. Find out why that dependency is failing.

Comment: Might be a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31665095/1531971 and https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/issues/104